# Freerdp issues while connecting to a terminal server

Tags: ubuntu, freerdp

Firstly i am sorry if i sound insane since i am very new here following is my question:

I am having an HPthin client(with Freerdp to version 1.1.1-hp14.6 and Ubuntu  12.04) with which I try to connect to a terminal windows server using smartcard and it's middleware installed on the thin client, if network level authentication is disabled on terminal server everything goes fine, this allows me to connect to terminal server using a smart card. The credentials are not passed from freerdp to the server. I get the login screen, accept the EULA, select sign in options, select the appropriate smart card and type in my smart card pin. This works, the problem is when I enable NLA (Network Level Authentication), I get an error on the thin client. Attached the image.
If someone could help to identify the issue, [image]please.